# Harder than usual deck of cards probability problem

Tags: probability

Charlie draws five cards out of a deck of 52. If he gets at least three cards of one suit, he discards the cards not of that suit, and draws as many cards as he discarded. What is the probability he ends up with five cards of the same suit?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  (And what if he doesn't get 3 cards of any one suit?)

Comment: Then I guess that's it. He doesn't draw or discard any.

Comment: A deliberately broad hint: try breaking your computation up into the cases where he gets exactly three cards of the suit, where he gets exactly four cards of the suit, and where he gets exactly 5 cards of the suit.

Comment: I'm thinking you begin with 4 * (13 c 3) * (39 c 2). Then do 4 * (13 c 4) * (39 c 1). Then 4 * (13 c 5) * (39 c 0). Something like that. Maybe?

Comment: I know it's all divided by (52 c 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**.  The probability is

- the probability of getting $5$ cards out of $52$, all of the same suit, on the first draw; plus
- the probability of getting $4$ cards out of $52$, all of the same suit, on the first draw, then $1$ of this suit from $47$ cards on the second draw; plus
- the probability of getting $3$ cards out of $52$, all of the same suit, on the first draw, then $2$ of this suit from $47$ cards on the second draw.

See if you can work out the numbers.

Comment: [4 * (13 c 5)] + [4 * (13 c 4) * (1/47)] + [4 * (13 c 3) * (1/47) * (1/46)]      All this divided by (52 c 5)?

Comment: You need to fix a few things.  First, you need to calculate probabilities at every step.  You can't just divide by $C(52,5)$ at the end because you are not always drawing $5$ cards, sometimes you are drawing more.

Comment: I would say divide the first part by 52 choose 5 and now it's correct. I don't know what two change on the other two parts though.

Comment: In the second part you have only considered choosing $4$ of the original $5$ cards, and the replacement card.  You have neglected the fifth original card.  Also, how many "successful" choices are there for the replacement?

Comment: Ohh. Multiply by (39 c 1) for the 5th card, which was not the same suit. Then instead of 1/47, put 9/47 because there are 9 left of that suit.

Comment: And then divide by. . . ?

Comment: I believe it would be 52 choose 5 times 9/47?

Comment: Can you fix your third term using similar considerations?

Comment: Final answer:  [(4 * (13 c 5)) / (52 c 5)] * [(4 * (13 c 4) * (39 c 1)) / ((52 c 5) * (9 / 47))] * [(4 * (13 c 3) * (39 c 2))/ ((52 c 5) * (9 / 47) * (9 / 46))]

Comment: plus in between the sections, not times

Comment: One more thing finally to think about: $(9/47)(9/46)$ is not right.  (Typo?)

Comment: I meant to write that. I was thinking incorrectly. You want to draw the card from that suit, so it would be (9/47)(8/46).

Comment: But at this stage you only have three cards from that suit in your hand, so there are still $10$ in the pack, so. . . ?

Comment: Then it would be (10/47)(9/46)

Comment: I think that's all correct now.